# HotSwapping Java classes in IntelliJ causes tomcat to restart

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea

Our company switched recently from `Eclipse to IntelliJ(UE)`. 
In Eclipse I had no problems hot swapping small Java class changes into the running tomcat. In IntelliJ however when I click "Update classes and resources" I get the notification that e.g. "1 class reloaded", and a few seconds after that the tomcat server restarts automatically. Nobody else at the company is experiencing that kind of problem and I'm pretty sure I use the same configuration they do.

How do I get true Hot Swap?

**Further info :**

**IDE -** IntelliJ IDEA 13.0.2
**OS -** Fedora 19

Thank you.

Comment: Are you using maven or anything?

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/updating-applications-running-on-application-servers.html

Comment: @Bart: Yes, we are using maven. Thanks for the link, but as I said I use the exact same settings as my colleagues and they don't have any problems.

Comment: I had the same problem using JRebel for hot deployment using maven. What I needed to do was remove the reloadContext option of the tomcat plugin in my pom.xml. Maybe it's useful in your case as well.